# How can i filter multiple fields with OR in Backand?

Tags: backand

i am passing filter value but its always matches both field where i need optional matches for this

> [ { "fieldName": "Firstname",    "operator": "equals",    "value":
>   "Megh"  }, { "fieldName": "Lastname",    "operator": "contains",
>   "value": "doot"  }]

Answer (score 4):

```
return $http ({
    method: 'GET',
    url: Backand.getApiUrl() + '/1/objects/users',
    params: {
      filter: {
        "q": { 
          { 
            "$or": [ { "firstName": { "$eq": "Megh" } }, { "lastName": {"$like": "doot"} } ]  
          }
        } 
      }
    }
  });
```

You can read further:
http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/apidocs/nosql_query_language/

There is also the "search" parameter that performs a free text search on all the textual fields in the object. Useful when you want to provide a free text search in your UI.

```
return $http ({
        method: 'GET',
        url: Backand.getApiUrl() + '/1/objects/users',
        params: {
          search: "something"
        }
      });
```

Comment: can you please guide me for SQL