# Backand - Add two filters to a GET request

Tags: backand

I'm doing a GET request to **/objects/items** and i want to filter the request on both:

[{ "fieldName": "title", "operator": "equals", "value": "someItem" }]

AND

[{ "fieldName": "description", "operator": "equals", "value": "someDescription" }]

Is this possible? Can only get it to work with one filter. Or any other way you can filter on the two in one api call?

[image]

Comment: found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350029/how-can-i-filter-multiple-fields-with-or-in-backand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter is an array that every item create an AND operator, so all you need is to join the {}, like this:

```
[{ "fieldName": "title", "operator": "equals", "value": "someItem" },
 { "fieldName": "description", "operator": "equals", "value":"someDescription" }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the noSQL syntax in case you need to do OR:

> {    "q": { "$or": [ { "title": "someItem" }, { "description": "someDescription" }  ]  }   }

See more examples of advanced filters: http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/apidocs/nosql_query_language/index.html#examples